# How to show list of phone contacts that are using same app as me?

Tags: android

I am creating a custom app for planning events. It has a SMS based authentication. Now I want to create a list of people who are already using the app (like the list of contacts in WhatsApp). Is there any way to do this in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right, you can do this in 3 steps:

1. When a user registers on your app, save the user in say "ActiveNumbers" database on your server.
2. Ask contacts permission from users.
3. Do a join of the contacts and ActiveNumbers table, list the valid contacts in the people section of your app.

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: You can accept this answer if it solves your problem. Feel free to comment if you need anything more. :)